# Move Margin Figure to Other Side

Tags: koma-script, sidenotes

I have margin figures on the right side of the page. How can I move them to the left side for all pages?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}
%



\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext

%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\marginfigure` actually uses `\marginnote`. Therefore, you can simply use `\reversemarginpar` and adjust the left margin appropriately. Further you have to tweak these

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@sidenotes@adjust}{%
 \hspace*{-120pt}%    %% this = marginparwidth + marginparsep 
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{margin={-120pt,0pt},font=footnotesize}
\makeatother
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    %% left adjusted to 142pt
\geometry{paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=142pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt}
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@sidenotes@adjust}{%
 \hspace*{-120pt}%    %% this = marginparwidth + marginparsep 
}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{margin={-120pt,0pt},font=footnotesize}
\makeatother
\reversemarginpar    %% use this
\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Introduction}

\blindtext
\begin{figure*}[htbp]%
%\centering
    \includegraphics[height=180pt,width=350pt]{example-image-c}%
    \caption{An even larger rectangle. This is the widest figure option. Both, the text as well as the margin width are used for the diagram.}
    \label{rectangle3}
\end{figure*}
\blindtext
%
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
%

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works well. When i  use figure*, result is not expected one. Figure does not occupy the left side space.

Comment: @sandu Answer updated. Is that sufficient?